# Matlab - Handle object properties of unique objects refer to the same object?

Tags: matlab, oop

I am confused on how to use handle objects as properties in matlab. For example, I defined the following classes:

```
classdef Page < handle
properties
    word1;
    word2;
end

classdef Book < handle
properties
    page1 = Page;
    page2 = Page;
end
```

Now I instantiate two books:

```
iliad = Book;
odyssey = Book;
```

If I check if iliad and odyssey are the same:

```
eq(iliad, odyssey)
```

I get:

```
ans = logical 0
```

So far so good

But if I check if page1 of iliad and odyssey are the same:

```
eq(iliad.page1, odyssey.page1)
```

I get:

```
ans = logical 1
```

This is not good! It means that if I change page1 of odyssey, page1 of iliad will also change. What am I misunderstanding? How do I deal with this issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This appears to be related to how MATLAB evaluates property default values. Per the documentation for [Properties Containing Objects](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/properties-containing-objects.html):

> MATLAB® evaluates property default values only once when loading the
>   class. MATLAB does not reevaluate the assignment each time you create
>   an object of that class. If you assign an object as a default property
>   value in the class definition, MATLAB calls the constructor for that
>   object only once when loading the class.

It goes on to further note that:

> Evaluation of property default values occurs only when the value is
>   first needed, and only once when MATLAB first initializes the class.
>   MATLAB does not reevaluate the expression each time you create an
>   instance of the class.

Which describes the equality you're seeing between books. MATLAB essentially [caches class definitions](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/modifying-and-reloading-classes.html), so while your `Page` objects are different within the book, they're going to be the same across books because MATLAB is only constructing the defaults once.

To avoid this, you can instantiate your `Page` objects in `Book`'s constructor:

```
classdef Book < handle
properties
    page1
    page2
end

methods
    function self = Book()
        self.page1 = Page;
        self.page2 = Page;
    end
end
end
```

Which gives you the desired behavior:

```
>> iliad = Book;
>> odyssey = Book;
>> eq(iliad.page1, odyssey.page1)

ans =

  logical

   0
```

Comment: Thank you! That answered my question beautifully, much appreciated!